# How to Iterate another model property Using Relationship inside MVC Razor Tabe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table in my MVC5 view that gets another property from a different model using the relationship between them but it is throwing error on that line...

This is the Razor Table

```
<div class="box-content nopadding">
                    <table class="table table-bordered dataTable dataTable-scroll-x">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <span class="span2">Branch(s)</span>
                                    <span class="span3">First Term</span>
                                    <span class="span3">Second Term</span>
                                    <span class="span3">Third Term</span>
                                    <span class="span1">Option</span>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in ViewData["Term"] as IEnumerable<_1._2._0_Core.Domains._2._1_Domain.AcademicFramework._1._1AcademicModels.Term>)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <span class="span2">@item.SchoolBranch.RegNo</span> // This is where the error is coming from because am trying to bring in another model property
                                    <span class="span3">@item.StartDate - @item.EndDate</span>
                                    <span class="span3">@item.StartDate() - @item.EndDate</span>
                                    <span class="span3">@item.StartDate - @item.EndDate</span>
                                    <span class="span1"><a href="@Url.Action("#")"class="btn"  rel="tooltip" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

this is the model definition

```
public class Term
{
    public string TermName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }

    public int SchoolBranchId { get; set; }
    public virtual SchoolBranch SchoolBranch { get; set; } //this is the relationship, i Used Fluent to map it

}
```

this is the Other Model that it is trying to get property from

```
 public class SchoolBranch : BaseEntity
{
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
    .....    
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Term { get; set; }
    .....

}
```

How can I get this property to display in that table using their relationship
Thank you for you time please

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult SessionDetail(int id)
    {
        ViewData["Term"] = _academicFramService.GetAllTerm(id);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: can you show how are you getting data in action?

Comment: Through my Controller

Comment: You should strongly type your views. That `as ...` is ugly. Also please post the error you are getting.

Comment: i assume you are getting data using EF and it uses deferred execution to load objects on demand, show your action how are you getting data

Comment: Just Edit the Question

Comment: am using `as...` because the view has two table in it the first tab view the table while the other add to the table... that why am using viewdata

Comment: This is the error message

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

`Line 49:                                         <span class="span2">@item.SchoolBranch.RegNo</span>`

Comment: ``item.SchoolBranch`` is _null_

Comment: Didn't get you please why is it null??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `GetAllTerm` method, you can use `Include` to load each `SchoolBranch` within the main query.

```
var db = ..; // the context instance

var query = db.Set<Term>()
    .Include(x => x.SchoolBranch)
    .Where(x => ... == id);
```

Comment: `public IEnumerable<Term> GetAllTerm(int session)
        {
            var getTerm = UnitOfWork.Term.GetTermBySessionId(session);

            return getTerm;
        }`

Comment: what is inside `GetTermBySessionId` method

Comment: that is were am using repository to include session and i just added include schoolbranch as you show me and it now working perfectly...

thank you very much for you help